# Loudtalks microphone

Tags: android

im not a programer and my english is basic take patience please, i try to explain my problem and i hope anybody helps my please, in loudtalks program I mapped a button to tap to open tap to close the microphone when speacks (the program leave's to map the button is very usefull turns the phone into a walkie), it’s perfect but the only problem i find is this feature only runs when the app is in first plane i need to open the mic while i see a map in the same phone or while i see another think, i try to remap a button in the stereo speackers while the phone is paired connected with stereo bluetooth speackers and the program not recognice any button but when i use the program “key test” the phone recognice one button in the stereo speackers later loudtalks recognice this button also and leave me to remap for use it for open close microphone very usefull but not runs if the program is in second plane, any idea to resolve this?? please it could be very usefull for me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Am I correct that you want the loudtalks app on your phone to keep working while you look at other apps? What phone do you have? What is the operating system on your phone?

---

Keep in mind that only one person can speak on a channel at time, and you can not interrupt anyone speaking for 10 seconds. Having said that, the problem it seems you are running into is that gingerbread is very aggressive at removing running applications from RAM, described here (http://lwn.net/Articles/317814/)

you can try using automateIt (https://market.android.com/details?id=AutomateIt.mainPackage&hl=en) to activate your walkietalkie app when you push a button

You can try turning "Lock home in memory" to enabled under performance settings

You could try the Project Elite ROM, which seems to support keeping an app in memmory

You could try Swapper2 (https://market.android.com/details?id=lv.n3o.swapper2&hl=en), or CompCache (Settings » CyanogenMod settings » Performance settings » Compcache), which help the memmory management issue if your device supports it by using a swap file.

You could try superCharger here (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1126940) or here (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=991276), and try their process for "bulletproofing" background apps here (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1012330)

The only other option I could think of is compiling your own CM7 version where you put your app as a systemapp which gets ignored by the memmory manager... but that's a much more complex issue

Comment: yes the app is working in second plane can receive messages and they are reproduced automatically when the app is in second plane but cannot open the microphone to speack if the program is not in the first plane.. i want to use the mapped key for open the mic when i looking another app.

Comment: sorry HTC wildfire with cyanogen mod7 gingerbread 2.3.7

Comment: updated answer to reflect new info :)

Comment: Hi! thankyou very much x your time, i try all automatelt is not the solution... the other no results, with bulletprof it's possible i can make any but i don't know the name of the process to keep in memory i think the mapped key only runs when loudtalks is in first plane because a process only appears if this stay in first plane i never can see the name.. :S i don't know if this is the way... if i can make a log of services running while 30 seconds i can see the name of this service..and i can try to keep in memory with bulletproof

Comment: how can i make a log of services and proceses while a short real time?